# Is there a formula to increment by 0.1 to an alphanumeric code in Excel, and then repeat the pattern?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, alphanumeric

I'm trying to make a column going all the way down like this:

```
C00
C00.1
C00.2
C00.3
C00.4
C00.5
C00.6
C00.7
C00.8
C00.9
C01
C01.0
C01.1
C01.2
C01.3
....
C01.9
C02
C02.0
C02.1
```

AND SO ON.

Is there a way to do this easily on Excel? So far I've just been doing the drag and drop after each x0x.0, but I'd really just like to automate this and save time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pattern at the beginning (C00 then C00.1) is a bit different from later on (C01 then C01.0) - might be worth clarifying if this is intentional. If so, it would make things a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method.

Enter this formula in the first cell in which you want the number.

```
=TEXT((ROW()-1)/10,"""C"""& IF(MOD(ROW(),10)=1,"00","00.0"))
```

Adjust the `-1` to the number you need, depending upon the row number and result number you want. As the formula is it will write the number "C00.1" if entered in row 2. Note that the "1" in the expression `MOD(ROW(),10)=1` is the same absolute number as the "-1" just mentioned. This expression determines which is each 10th number that needs a different format.

Copy down the formula for as far as you need the numbering. You may wish to change the formulas to hard text. If so, Select > Copy > Paste Special > Values.